# Does Kojou Akatsuki have two kids?

Tags: strike-the-blood

Does the fourth progenitor, Kojou Akatsuki, have two kids — one with Himeragi Yukina and another one with Asagi Aiba?

Well, when I saw the last episode it did not seem like that to me. However, many sites like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_the_Blood) claim so.

Can anyone give me definite evidence? (if possible with pictures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer your question,

> yes, Kojou has 2 kids.

According to Wikipedia and from what I remember,

> Yukina and Kojou has a kid that looks a lot like Yukina except for a few minor differences like the eyes. Yukina's kid, Reina, has Kojou's eyes and can also summon familiars like Kojou. Not much is known about Moegi, Kojou's kid with Asagi, except that she sent Reina back in time to chase a man-made magical beast that I believe attacked Kojou and Yukina.

You can read more about it in these links:

- http://strike-the-blood.wikia.com/wiki/Reina_Akatsuki
- http://strike-the-blood.wikia.com/wiki/Moegi_Akatsuki

Comment: Wait, isn't Moegi the computer program that is partner of Asagi?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was evident in the last episode of season 1. In the end, you can see that there was another girl who was the daughter of Asagi.

Comment: Can you provide some sources for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kojou has a kid, but I believe that Moegi isn't Asagi's and Kojou's child.

The reason why I think this is because Asagi's hair was originally black, so I don't get it why Moegi's hair is greenish yellowish. And on the last episode of season 1, Reina said, "I got to see [my] dad before he died." Moegi responded, "No no no, [that man] can never die.